# How should renderer class relate to the class it renders?

Tags: c#, architecture, rendering

I am working on making a Pong clone as a practice project. I have a `PongState` class with members like `Ball`, `Paddle`, `Board` and `Score`. I want to structure my code so that each object doesn't have to know how to render itself, but a `PaddleRenderer` class will. I also want to create a `PongStateRenderer` class, which may use other classes like `PaddleRenderer`, as well.

How should I let `PongStateRenderer` know about the internals of `PongState` so that it can render it? The `Ball` object in `PongState` know's it's own position and size, does that mean `Ball` has to be a public member variable so that `PongStateRenderer` can also know the position, or is there a better way to do this without totally breaking encapsulation? Perhaps my architecture is totally wrong, and I should use a different method?

I'm working in C# as it says in the tag but a general answer that applies to many languages could also be helpful.

Comment: You are doibg exactly the opposite of what a nornal game would do. In those the renderer usually doesn't know how to render something, only the objects themselfs.

Comment: You seem to be asking "how do I get object A to see values in object B using encapsulation", and to a lesser degree, "is this a bad program structure". This seems more like a *programming* question. The same questions may arise when dealing with, say, data structures for the purpose of displaying data in non-gaming software. As such, I would vote to move this to StackExchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're just taking a baby step away from "objects render themselves" rather than moving all the way to an approach where something else renders the objects. When objects render themselves, every object (in this case a paddle, a ball, et cetera) has a `draw` method and some corresponding data. In your case you just appear to be moving that method and state into its own class, so you'd still have a `PaddleRenderer` and a `BallRenderer` and so on. I would argue this is inferior, as it doesn't really solve many of the problems associated with the "objects render themselves" approach.

Instead, I would encourage you to think more broadly: generally you can visually represent things in one of two broad classes: sprites or 3D meshes. Your renderer should know how to render sprites, and it should know how to render meshes. Let's say for simplicity everything in your game is represented and rendered as sprites. So you create a `Sprite` class that contains all the needed properties: references to textures, animation sequence information and current state, position, current sequence index, current frame index, et cetera.

Then you give your `Paddle` a `Sprite*`, and you give you `Ball` a `Sprite*`, and you configure the data on each sprite to be appropriate for the ball, or the paddle, or whatever else you want to put in the game. But the renderer just has this big homogeneous list of `Sprite` objects to render and that's all it concerns itself with.

Every tick of the game logic, you update the ball's position and the paddle positions and all of that. Once the logic tick completes, before you actually render, you can simply copy that position information into the appropriate sprite member before rendering. Likewise with any other state (for example maybe you update the sprite's tint color randomly every time the ball hits a paddle, for a psychedelic effect).

This approaches makes the "renderer" subordinate to the game logic, but that's reasonable. Generally in a game you'll have user input which directs the game logic, and then game logic which directs the rendering. Information (and responsibility) flows along those paths, but it *generally* does not flow in the other direction (the renderer usually does not influence the state of the game logic).

Comment: This. Remember that in game development, usually composition works much better than complex hierarchies of inheritance.